# Insert NULL instead of empty string with PDO

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, null, bindparam

I have a table which has some nullable fields and when the user enters nothing into the HTML form field, I want to insert NULL into that field, not an empty string (this is important as some of my SELECTs on these tables later use conditions such as WHERE x IS NOT NULL).

However, this version of bindParam code inserts an empty string into the nullable field instead of NULL.

```
$stmt2->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

I've been reading quite a bit and figured out that this is the answer to insert null into the field instead:

```
$stmt2->bindParam(':title', $title, PDO::PARAM_NULL);
```

But this means I need to pre-check all parameters that are being passed to nullable fields to determine if they are empty, and if so pass the `PDO::PARAM_NULL` instead of `PDO::PARAM_STR`. I can of course do this, but was hoping there might be a setting which would just tell PDO if it encounters an empty string, insert null instead.

I stumbled across this

```
$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS, PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING);
```

But it has no effect and with further research I'm thinking this only affects record on the way out, not on the way in.

Any options other than pre-checking the variables?

Comment: See also: [Insert NULL instead of empty values using MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16586255/1839439)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want null, just insert `null` instead of empty string.

```
$stmt2->bindValue(':title', $title === '' ? null : $title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides xdazz's more appropriate answer, you can often solve something like this in SQL: Just rephrase the query `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?)` to something like `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (NULLIF(?, ''))`.

Answer (score -1):

This works really well. Another option is with

```
IF $val == null || $val == 'null' || $vall ==''
BindValue with PDO::PARAM_NULL
ELSE
BindValue with PDO::PARAM_STR
```